# "Snow in the sole of a shoe" or "snow on the sole of a shoe?"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What's the correct construction?

Example sentence:

> I waddled through the winter streets. There was snow *on/in* the sole of
>   my shoes.

Comment: 'On'. I think you pluralise 'sole' as well, so 'soles of my shoes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sole is only the bottom part of the shoe, and is a thin flat bit of leather/rubber.  Some soles (eg Dr Marten's) have air pockets inside, and so snow could get **inside** those soles.  But, most soles couldn't have snow inside them.

If there was a hole in the sole then it might let snow through into the **shoe**.

I think if the snow is stuck to the outside of the soles of your shoes then you'd say "There was snow on the soles of my shoes", and if it's actually come through into the shoes (making your feet cold and wet) you'd say "There was snow in my shoes".

Comment: I agree, but if I had snow or mud on the soles of a pair of shoes with deep patterns (like Doc Marten's) and I'd scraped off what what was on the surface I'd say that I had snow or mud in the _treads_ of my shoes. However I still wouldn't say I had it _in_ my soles for the reasons you gave.

Comment: @BoldBen I agree. I would never say I have *snow in the sole* (even with the meaning *in the tread*), although it sounds ok to me to say that I have *a bit of grit in the sole of my shoe* (meaning in the tread) so I think it comes down to context.

Comment: I would say "on the sole" or "in the tread" of my shoes.

Comment: In any event it would either be “in the ***soles*** of my shoes” or “ in the sole of one of my shoes.”  most likely the former in the case of caked on snow.